# Three-level variable in LME analysis - output

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, contrasts

I am currently unsure about a three-level variable in an linear mixed effects analysis in R (lme4) - I should add that I am new to LMEs and would very much appreciate some very basic advice!

I am trying to compare the results of an ANOVA with a corresponding LME analysis.
Regarding the 3x2x2 ANOVA, I was interested in how the 2x2 interaction might differ across the three levels of a third variable, where the three-way interaction was significant (outcome variable was response time in a behavioural experiment).

Regarding the LME, I sum-to-zero-coded all categorical predictors (since I was told that this would be preferable when assessing such interactions).
In the LME output (table obtained through the summary function/lmerTest package), there are now always two lines provided for the three-level predictor (predictor1.1 and predictor1.2), rather than one (as in the ANOVA analysis).

My question is whether this is correct or whether I made a mistake? Also, in case this is correct, how would one interpret such an outcome? For instance, if I was trying to assess the three-way interaction originally observed in the ANOVA, and the interaction predictor1.1 : predictor2 : predictor3 would turn out significant, whilst the interaction predictor1.2 : predictor2 : predictor3 would not reach significance, how would I report/interpret this finding?

My apologies in advance in case this is a question with a very obvious answer; as I said, I am used to ANOVAs and don't really have anyone around who is familiar with LMEs. I would really appreciate your advice!
Kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a categorical predictor, the summary of a regression model like this will report a number of lowest-level coefficients one less than its number of levels, and also for higher-level interactions of that predictor with other predictors.

It's risky to evaluate any single coefficient associated with that predictor (whether at the individual level or in an interaction), as the difference of its value from 0 (and thus its apparent "significance") depends on how the predictor was coded: sum-to-zero versus treatment/dummy coding, or the choice of reference level in treatment coding. Trying to interpret individual coefficients tends to lead to extensive confusion, often represented in questions on this site.

To compare against the ANOVA output you need a joint test on all the levels of the 3-level categorical predictor. The `Anova()` function (note the capital "A") in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) is a common choice for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful response, the output for the three-level categorical variable looks much more sensible now than with the summary() function.
Many thanks, I really appreciate the fast and helpful reply! :-)